# Acentuação na impressão e campos em branco

Tags: c++, while, acentuação

Boas povo,
Estou a pouquíssimo tempo desbravando o mundo dos developers, então precisarei de um desconto pelos muitos erros no meu programinha. Não achei uma resposta aq, então perguntarei.

O programa abaixo deve simplesmente cadastrar 5 pessoas e imprimir na tela quando solicitado. Mas apesar de o programa estar acentuando nos menus, na hora de imprimir na tela os dados cadastrados eles não aparecem.

Outra coisa seria; não deixar o usuário "pular" partes do cadastro, ou seja, necessariamente antes de continuar o cadastro a pessoa deva escrever algo, nem que seja uma letra. Algo como um loop, mas para caracteres aleatórios..

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

struct cad{
int codigo;
char nome[50];
char email[50];
char telefone[20];
};

int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    struct cad ficha [5];
    int vetor [5];
    int cod=1, op, i, j, info=0;
    char novo;
    do{
        printf("\n****  Base cadastral  ****\n");
        printf(" Selecione uma opção do Menu: \n\n");
        printf(" 1 - Insira um novo cadastro    \n");
        printf(" 2 - Mostrar todos os cadastros \n");
        printf(" 0 - Sair                       \n");
        printf("\nDigite a opção desejada: ");
        scanf("%d",&op);
        fflush(stdin);
        system("cls");
        switch (op){
            case 0: 
                printf (" Finalizando programa\n");
                break;
                
            case 1:
                do{
                    if( info > 4 ){
                        printf("\n\nLista cheia\n\n");
                        system("pause");
                        system("cls");
                        break;
                    }
                
                for (i=0; i<5; i++){
                vetor [i] = rand()%5;
                    for (j=0; j<i; j++){
                        if (vetor [i] == vetor [j]);
                        vetor[i] = (rand()%5);
                    }
                } 
                ficha[info].codigo = cod;            
                printf ("\nNovo Cadastro\n");
                printf (" Número de cadastro %d", cod); 
                
                printf("\n Insira nome:\n ");
                gets(ficha[info].nome);
                fflush(stdin);
                                
                printf ("\n insira email\n ");
                gets (ficha[info].email);
                fflush(stdin);
                    
                printf ("\n insira telefone\n ");
                gets (ficha[info].telefone);
                fflush(stdin);
                
                printf (" Pessoa cadastrada com sucesso!\n\n");
                printf (" -----------------------------------\n");
                system("\npause");
                system("cls");
                
                cod = cod + 1;              
                info = info + 1;
                
                printf("\n Cadastrar outra pessoa? S/N ");
                novo = getch();
                system("cls");                          
                }while(toupper(novo) != 'N' ); 
                break;
                
            case 2:
                if(info==0){
                printf("\n Sem cadastros \n");
                system("\npause");
                system("cls");
                }
                else
                    for (i=0;i<info;i++){
                    printf (" Código %d\n",ficha[i].codigo);
                    printf (" Nome %s\n",ficha[i].nome);
                    printf (" Email %s\n",ficha[i].email);
                    printf (" Telefone %s\n",ficha[i].telefone);
                    printf ("\n");
                    }
                printf("\n\n" );
                system ("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
                
            default:
                printf("Opção inválida!\n");
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
            }
    }while(op != 0);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Creio que aqui: `if (vetor [i] == vetor [j]);` não deva ter este `;` final pois você está executando um comando nulo em seu loop e, creio, o que deseja é sortear um novo número. Não sei se o que pretende é evitar duplicatas mas se for esta sua lógica pode não evitar.

Comment: opa, vlw pelo feedback. vou arrumar essa parte.

Comment: Bom dia Sr Uma ideia é verificar o tamanho da string para isso recomendo a utilização do [strlen();] (https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strlen) no caso fazendo a validação com x caractere.